# Foreach through JSON stdClass Object array in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, foreach, stdclass

I am fetching a JSON api in PHP, then I am attempting to iterate through the array with a `foreach($obj['result'] as $c)` loop. I'm specifically trying to loop through the [result] nested array, but the returned `stdClass Object` is not letting me do it. I have attempted to use `$obj = get_object_vars($obj)` but that doesn't seem to work for the `$obj['result']` lower nested array. Any ideas what I do here to foreach through the `$obj['result']` ?

```
$json = file_get_contents($rink);
$obj = array();
$obj = json_decode($json);
```

When I use php `print_r()` I get.

```
stdClass Object (
[status] => 1
[message] => OK
[result] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [blockNumber] => 10271028
                [timeStamp] => 1646413513
                [hash] => 0xab6f7d30aec4f...
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [blockNumber] => 10271028
                [timeStamp] => 1646413513
                [hash] => 0xab6f7d30aec4f...
            )
    )
)
```

Php foreach attempted loop

```
foreach($obj['result'] as $c) {
    echo $c['hash'] . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: use `json_decode($json, true)` to get an array instead of object.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
foreach($obj['result'] as $c) {
    echo $c['hash'] . '<br>';
}
```

to

```
foreach($obj->result as $c) {
    echo $c->hash . '<br>';
}
```

Object key value is accessed with `->` operator in php.

Comment: It should be `$obj->result`

Comment: @Barmar yes I never noticed thank you.